# htaccess redirect to a maintenance page and remove filename with extansion from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've have this code in my htaccess which redirects to the maintenance page, but I can't make it to redirect without showing a folder name and filename (/mce/mce.php) and show only the domain url like domain.com/website:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/website/mce/mce.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /website/mce/mce.php [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/

RewriteRule \.(jpe?g?|png|gif|ics|css|js)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4
RewriteRule . /website/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4
RewriteRule ^ mce/mce.php [L]
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. It's almost there, but I'd prefer everything what comes after `domain.com/website` like `domain.com/website/fr/file` will show just domain `domain.com/website` and also I lose background.png if I only enter `domain.com/website` but if I add something after it then the background is ok.

Comment: I'm getting error: `The page isn’t redirecting properly`

Comment: it doesn't redirect at all, it shows my website but without css

Comment: first I start with `domain.com/website` but if I enter `domain.com/website/dd/ee` it cuts the everything after `website` and shows my website firstpage without css

Comment: if I enter `domain.com/website/`it shows my website (without css) but should show maintenance page (mce.php). My css file for the website is at `domain.com/website/css` but the mce.php and background.png are in the same folder `mce` (only these two files are there, for that I use only inline styles). Redirection should only work for mce.php anything else should stop, and this folder mce should be allowed to read png, jpg files. Redirection shouldn't work only for my IP.

Comment: I had this already in my website, but after your last posted answer edit, it doesn't even redirect to mce.php.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was using word "redirect" in the meaning of showing the mce.php content. That's what I need.

Comment: I don't know what is going on. I have only the rules copied from your answer (nothing else). I'm changing IP for `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1` and it works fine my website shows for me, then I change the IP for something else and enter the same url `domain.com/website/` it shows also my website firstpage but without css styles what is of course wrong because it should show the mce.php content. this is strange.

Comment: No, this is not the thing. You just added more extensions to allow. The problem with these rules is that it doesn't show `mce.php` content at all. It shows my index.php content.

Comment: If I delete everything form htaccess it also goes to index.php. If I copy/paste the rules from my question post it works fine (but not as I would like to), but when I copy/paste your rules it doesn't work at all (not showing mce.php content). I don't know what this line do `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` maybe I don't have switched some option in my apache config for that?

Comment: when I delete the second part of rules `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4
RewriteRule ^$ mce/mce.php [L]` nothing is changing to situation when there are all, so it seems like this part of rules is not executing.

Comment: As I wrote above everything is executing and working perfectly fine on my Apache.

Comment: YES!!!! it's working now, I had to change the second part of rules for this: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ mce/mce.php [L]` or the last line can be `RewriteRule . mce/mce.php [L]` and now is working as it should be! Acutally I don't know why `^` or `.` but it seems that with each one of them works fine.

Comment: I wouldn't have done this without your help! Thank you.